# ICriteria query - finding objects whith certain properties in their lists

Tags: nhibernate

I have a class B which contains a string 'b'. I also have a class A which contains a list of Bs (IList) called list.

I would like to find all distinct objects of A which contain B objects that contain the string 'bla' in the string 'b'.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
session.CreateQuery(@"
        select distinct a
        from A a
        join a.Bs b
        where b.b = 'bla'
        ").List<A>();
```

If the relationship is bidirectional (i.e. B has a reference to A), it's even easier:

```
select distinct b.A
from B b
where b.b = 'bla'
```

I assumed you meant B.b equals 'bla'. If you meant bla is *part of* B.b, you can use the `LIKE` operator just like in SQL

Comment: Thanks. SQL and HQL is ok but I was wondering how to do this with ICriteria. I suppose I have to create some alias like list.b ???

Comment: I really don't remember how to do it with Criteria. But why do you need that?

Comment: I am using some existing stuff which has, for example, a method like this: ICriteria GetPagedCriteria<T>(PagedRequest request, bool sort)

Comment: You're unnecessarily limiting yourself. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/#hg/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns/Pagination